# Can't use MySql for Spring Greenhouse project?

Tags: java, spring

I just checked out the Spring Greenhouse project as a first step to learn Spring Security.
The project works fine but I was wondering about the following scenarios:

There are two configurations: standard and embedded. The javadoc says the embedded is default. I am not sure how to make it run in standard mode. Has anybody has tried this before?

Secondly in embedded mode I modified the code slightly with the following code to run it with MySql but to my surprise the application is not starting up at all. It throws the following error:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Unable to determine database version", e);

@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    // EmbeddedDatabaseFactory factory = new EmbeddedDatabaseFactory();
    // factory.setDatabaseName("greenhouse");
    // factory.setDatabaseType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.);
    DriverManagerDataSource mysqldataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    mysqldataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    mysqldataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/greenhouse?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8");
    mysqldataSource.setUsername("root");
    mysqldataSource.setPassword("mysql");
    return populateDatabase(mysqldataSource);       
}
```

Can anybody please help me on this?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: can you explain populateDatabase method?

Comment: Can you post stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. 
There was a tag in web.xml and i changed there from embedded to standard. 
The problem was in the sql query which was creating the database version table was not mysl complaint. There were other queries also which were not mysql complaint. I changed the sql query and now eveything worked like as expected. The next thing I am gonna do is use some kind og generic database query generator so that i don't have to change the query if in future I change my mind to use post gre sql in place of my sql. 
Thank you for all your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the exception you're getting, the file you're interested in is [GenericDatabaseUpgrader.java](http://git.springsource.org/greenhouse/greenhouse/blobs/c1c18b31a9e894bd4fc1b55e909cfdc90e24972b/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/versioned/GenericDatabaseUpgrader.java#line93)

More than half the code there refers to `DatabaseVersion` which is a table that is created if absent.
Since I doubt you already have it and judging by the exception type (`SQLException`), I'm inclined to say it's failing to create/insert/retrieve the referenced table.

You can check if you have the table and go from there.

Also, judging by the code you're trying to inject, I'd also look at `connection = dataSource.getConnection()` as a possible culprit.

P.S. Regarding standard/embedded, it appears you can VM parameters or maven settings to switch between the two. Please check [the official forums and specifically this topic for info](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-111250.html?s=fbc27b325da5c1273304f326366e169d)